# find the path of a data extension for a SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to find the path of a data extension that I use in a SQL Query.

I can find the name of it but because the data extension structure is very messy is hard to find it.

Is there a way in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to see that? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's a script for that. Replace `<DATA EXTENSION NAME>` with the name of your DE.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
var deName="<DATA EXTENSION NAME>";
var FolderScript= DataExtension.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:deName});
({Property:"CustomerKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:key}); 
var FolderID = FolderScript[0].CategoryID;
var results = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:FolderID});

var folderName = results [0].Name;
var parentFolder=results [0].ParentFolder.Name;
var countdown = function(id) {
    if (id> 0) {
        var results = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:id});
    Write(results [0].Name+">");
        return countdown(results[0].ParentFolder.ID);
    } else {
        return id;
    }
};
countdown(FolderID);
</script>
```

See my blog post for further enhancements to the above script: [Find a Data Extension and it’s folder path using SSJS](http://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/14/find-a-data-extension-and-its-folder-path-using-ssjs/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to marketing cloud. Not sure where do I run the script, can you give me a hint please

Comment: WebStudio>CloudPages. Create a new collection, inside the collection create a new landing page. Add a plain HTML content block and paste it there. Hit publish, and the path will be displayed on-screen. No need to actually publish it.

Comment: CodeRage, I have updated my question with a screenshot. It doesn't seem to work. I have changed the data extension name with different data extension names but it doesn't show anything

Comment: Click on Publish in top right corner and take out the `<>` around DE name

Comment: I have already, it doesn't make any difference. I can upload another screenshot if you want

Comment: Show us what happens when you hit Publish. Just click on Publish and wait for a minute.

Comment: sorry, the problem was the brackets. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, and please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest this chrome extension '[SFMC OBJECT FINDER](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sfmc-object-finder/bkicfdfanedgnlddinjiojphnehpjnpd)'

> Users find difficult to track down a Object location from the Salesforce Marketing Cloud platform.
>
> This extension would help users to search for a Object from the platform and display the exact location.